# Positioning 5 resizable divs on a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set position for 5 divs like on pic, and use for this bootstrap grid. Now I have 3 rows so div1 and div4 on first row, div2 and div5 on second row, and div3 on third row, each of this divs is resizable (I'm using CSS property class "resize")

So,
first problem is then I resize div 1 so div 4 jump to bottom under div 1
second problem is cause I'm using rows of bootstrap, my left side longer then right side, and it doesn't allow me to set it equal

What's the best way to resolve this problems?

[image]

this my code now

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="childTree">
                <div id="industry"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="parentGrid" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
                <table id="table">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="parentTree">
                <div id="clinical"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="childGrid">
                    <div id="tree-container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="childTree">
                <div id="study"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: some code of your attempts would be usefull to you to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have considered flex ? *[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaZLxg)*

```css
/* add resize for demo on hover */

div:hover {
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 150px;
}
/* end demo with resize on :hover */

main,
aside,
section,
div {
  display: flex;
}
section,
div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 25vw;
}
aside,
section,
div {
  flex-flow: column;
}
div {
  border: solid #5B8EC4;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9EC5FD, #468BD2) #5B8EC4;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
html,
body,
main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
body {
  border: solid #5B8EC4;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <div> run snippet in full page mode to notice behavior in good condition</div>
    <div>2
    </div>
    <div>3
    </div>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div>4
    </div>
    <div>5
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

snippet without height but content and resize handles:

```css
main,
aside,
section,
section>div 
aside>div{
  display: flex;
}

p {
  resize: both;
}


section> div ,
aside>div{
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  flex: 2
}

aside,
section,
section > div ,
aside> div{
  flex-flow: column;
}
aside {  
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  width:25vw;/* some width to start with */
}
aside,
section {
  background: gray;
  padding:1em;
}

section > div,
aside > div {

  border: solid #5B8EC4;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9EC5FD, #468BD2) #5B8EC4;
  color: white;
  margin: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div div {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  color: white;
  height:100%;
}

html,
body,
main {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  padding: 1em;
}

body {
  border: solid #5B8EC4;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <aside>
    <div>
    <div>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.Aenean ultricies mi vitae est</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div>
    <div>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: so how I got it, i need to take out whole bootstrap grid?

Comment: @Anton nop, i do not think so, here html is used for height reference in the demo and becomes max-height somehow, it could be heights sets from one or more div or just from their content. a parent's height could be used or even a static height on main.If there is content, all containers will expand to fill height from the tallest column without height set on parent

Comment: doesn't allow me to resize aside and section at all, i guess "flex" kills it

Comment: @Anton   how do you resize it ?

Comment: I've added resize: horizontal; to aside

Comment: I see , thought you did it  in js, so you need an extra wrapper to keep away from flex properties: demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPbJab or remove flex value (div div or & aside without flex value)